# Codeigniter can't redirect using php code when calling one of its methods via AJAX

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I need to know why it can't redirect to login page when there is no session using ajax called.

***This is my controller:**
I put my library "MY_Login" in constructor

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library("MY_Login");
    }

    public function index()
    {
       $this->load->view('admin/dashboard_view');
    }

    public function test(){
        echo '^^';
    }
}
```

***This is my library:**
it is for check session

```
class MY_Login extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // call with constructor.
        $this->isLogin();
    }

    function isLogin() {

        // if there is no session existed
        if(!$this->session->userdata('USR_NM')){

            // redirect to login page
            redirect('/login', 'refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

***Ajax:**
When there is no session, I try to access function "test()" inside my controller "dashbaord" using Jquery Ajax called. but it seem can't reidrect to my login page.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I am sure you can redirect, but that is not what you want, I imagine you want the page calling the ajax to redirect.  Just because you redirect the ajax response doesn't mean the page sitting client side knows anything about that..  You have to send a message back to the client and then use javascript to redirect the page, not the ajax request.

Comment: How are you making the ajax call?

Comment: I got you, Thanks ^^

Comment: Please help to answer my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606665/how-to-stop-execute-other-controller-after-response-to-ajax-codeigniter).

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to redirect your ajax request.  This is not what you want, you want to redirect the page that is rendered to the client.

You will have to send a message back to the ajax call telling it to redirect the page -via- javascript.

Just because you redirect the ajax request means nothing to the page that is already rendered to the client.

Answer (score 0):

the page won't redirect since page on client side doesn't know about the response you received through ajax request...  check your console and you will know whats going on.
What you can do is if session is not set then send 'false' as response and then you can do something like:

```
if(!response){
    location.href='link to which you want the page to redirect'.
}
```